# Problems with "rvmsudo"

Tags: ruby, rvm, thin

I am using RVM running Ruby 1.9.3. When I try to run thin via:

```
rvmsudo thin start -p 90
```

I get:

```
sudo: thin: command not found
```

My `gem list` tells me I have `thin (1.5.0)` installed. 
Also, `rvmsudo which ruby` returns:

```
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
```

but `rvmsudo ruby -v` returns:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [x86_64-linux]
```

I am not sure what's going on. My main concern is to run `thin`, but I am also surprised that `which` returns Ruby 1.9.3 but `ruby -v` returns 1.8.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update RVM using:

```
rvm get head
```

It's a bug:
https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1337